# Spring framework error page not found

Tags: spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

> Feb 22, 2015 9:45:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/NECSTUDIO/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'necstudio'

Please help.

Comment: be more specific can you share your controller class and jsf page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No Handler found` means that the dispatcher could not find a controller (=handler) to forward the request to.
You need a request-mapping to map paths to controller-methods.
For you case you need a request-mapping that matches the request path `/NECSTUDIO`. 
This is done by annotating a Controller and/or controller-method with the `@RequestMapping` annotation (I'm assuming that you've properly set up spring-mvc and component-scanning, and the dispatcher servlet-mapping to be `/*`).

```
@Controller
class NecStudioController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/NECSTUDIO")
    @RequestBody
    public String index() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```